# Can moderators hide edit history?

Tags: discussion, moderation

Based upon [Is there a way to hide edit history of question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/275837/298072), I flagged a question where the initial edit included the `root` users credentials to log into the OP's server to see if this edit can be hidden further

> The initial revision of this answer included details for the root user to the OP's server, is it possible to hide these details further?

Which was declined as

> flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

Fair enough, but is there anything extra a moderator could actually do?

The users details had already been edited out prior to flagging the post.

Comment: Whoever they are really needs to change their credentials.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<strike>Moderators can't.</strike>

As [@JonClements](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1252759/jon-clements) [mentioned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319640/can-moderators-hide-edit-history/319641#comment326034_319641), moderators [can redact revisions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191121/allow-moderators-to-hide-a-revision/274274):

> *No longer true. Moderators can now redact revisions - it takes one mod to make the redaction and another to approve it.* – Jon Clements♦

Cases like these should probably be flagged, so moderators can have a look at it.

That said, if a user is stupid enough to post that kind of credentials online, that user should always change their credentials.

Comment: No longer true. Moderators can now redact revisions - it takes one mod to make the redaction and another to approve it.

Comment: Well I'll be darned. Editing.

Comment: For reference: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191121/allow-moderators-to-hide-a-revision/274274

Comment: Good to know! This just begs the question how serious it needs to be to have an edit redacted since mine was declined. Hopefully I haven't eluded to which post it was so only those that can see my flags would be able to find out

Comment: @Sayse that would be true if you hadn't of edited it :p

Comment: @JonClements - Ha! I'll try to be less helpful in the future :p

Comment: @Sayse I've deleted it anyway - couldn't see it going anywhere - so you're fine :p